# 413 Request Entity Too Large WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I've seen the other posts on this topic and think I have tried everything and can't seem to resolve this error when trying to save a larger file.  I have bumped up the maxReceivedMessageSize and all the other size related configs in both  sections of the config files and also have bumped up the uploadReadAheadSize via IIS Manager.  I don't see what I could be missing so I'll post my config files in hopes someone might be able to spot something wrong.

Service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c5rge93gerg9" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
      <client>
         <endpoint address="/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyHttpBinding" contract="*" name="Default" />
      </client>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyHttpBinding" hostNameComparisonMode="Exact" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Relevant portion of Client config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="MyHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
    name="MyHttpBinding" />
</client>
```

Comment: how large is the file?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Only about 2MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `<services>` section in your service config, so even though you've defined a binding with larger values, it's not being used because it's not set as the default binding nor is it explicitly assigned to an endpoint.  Instead, you're getting a `basicHttpBinding` with the default quotas and limits.

In your situation, the simplest fix is to probably fix the service's config file and remove the `<client>` section and add a `<services>` section, like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyServiceName">
    <endpoint address="/" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="MyHttpBinding" 
              contract="*" 
              name="Default" />
  </service>
</services>
```

This will assign the "MyHttpBinding" configuration to your endpoint.

Note that you can also make the "MyHttpBinding" the default configuration for all `basicHttpBinding` endpoints by omitting the `name` attribute.